# Query items from granchildren objects

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask python application that has a set of related tables that are chained together through foreign keys. I would like to be able to return an aggregate list of records from one table that are related to a distant table. However, I am struggling to understand how sqlalchemy does this through object relationships.

For example, there are three objects I'd like to join (challenge and badge) with two tables (talent_challenge and badge) to be able to query for all badges related to a specific challenge. In SQL, this would look something like:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name 
FROM badge b
INNER JOIN talent_challenge tc ON tc.talent_id = b.talent_id
WHERE tc.challenge_id = 21
```

The 'talent' and 'challenge' tables are not needed in this case, since I only need the talent and challenge IDs (in 'talent_challenge') for the relationship. All of the interesting detail is in the badge table.

I am able to use sqlalchemy to access the related talent from a challenge using:

```
talents = db.relationship('TalentModel', secondary='talent_challenge')
```

And I can then reference `talent.badges` for each of those talents to get the relevant badges related to my initial challenge. However, there can be redundancy, and this list of badges isn't contained in a single object.

A stripped-down version of the three models are:

```
class TalentModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'talent'

    # Identity
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Relationships
    challenges = db.relationship('ChallengeModel', secondary='talent_challenge',)
    # badges (derived as backref from BadgeModel)

class ChallengeModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'challenge'

    # Identity
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    member_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('member.id'))

    # Relationships
    talents = db.relationship('TalentModel', secondary='talent_challenge', order_by='desc(TalentModel.created_at)')

class BadgeModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'badge'

    # Identity
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    talent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('talent.id'))

    # Parents
    talent = db.relationship('TalentModel', foreign_keys=[talent_id], backref="badges")
```

I also have a model for the associative table, 'talent_challenge':

```
class TalentChallengeModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'talent_challenge'

    # Identity
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    talent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('talent.id'))
    challenge_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('challenge.id'))

    # Parents
    talent = db.relationship('TalentModel', uselist=False, foreign_keys=[talent_id])
    challenge = db.relationship('ChallengeModel', uselist=False, foreign_keys=[challenge_id])
```

I would like to better understand sqlalchemy (or specifically, flask-sqlalchemy) to allow me to construct this list of badges from the challenge object. Is `db.session.query` of BadgeModel my only option?

UPDATED 1/23/2015:
My blocker on my project was solved by using the following:

```
@property
def badges(self):
    from app.models.sift import BadgeModel
    from app.models.relationships.talent import TalentChallengeModel
    the_badges = BadgeModel.query\
        .join(TalentChallengeModel, TalentChallengeModel.talent_id==BadgeModel.talent_id)\
        .filter(TalentChallengeModel.challenge_id==self.id)\
        .all()
    return the_badges
```

Wrapping the query in a function got around the issues I was having with the name `BadgeModel` not being defined and not being able to be imported in the model otherwise. The `@property` decorator allows me to just reference this as `challenge.badges` later in the view.

However, I am still interested in understanding how to do this as a relationship. Some searching elsewhere led me to believe this would work:

```
badges = db.relationship('BadgeModel',
    secondary="join(BadgeModel, TalentChallengeModel, BadgeModel.talent_id == TalentChallengeModel.talent_id)",
    secondaryjoin="remote([id]) == foreign(TalentChallengeModel.challenge_id)",
    primaryjoin="BadgeModel.talent_id == foreign(TalentChallengeModel.talent_id)",
    viewonly=True,
    )
```

Because of other unresolved issues in my application environment, I can't fully test this (e.g., adding this code breaks Flask-User in my site) but would like to know if this is correct syntax and if there is any disadvantage to this over the query-in-function solution.